# Setting a variable to the active element inside an iframe

Tags: typescript

I want to set the original focused element to that of the active element inside an iFrame. This is the original function I have.

```
// Original
public componentWillMount(): void {
this._originalFocusedElement = getDocument()!.activeElement as HTMLElement;
}

// My attempt
public componentWillMount(): void {
this._originalFocusedElement = i.getDocument()!.activeElement!.contentWindow.document.activeElement
}
```

However it gives me compilation errors

`[ts] Property 'contentWindow' does not exist on type 'Element'. [2339]`

Could someone suggest how I can set the `_originalFocusedElement` to the active element inside the iframe ?

Answer (score 0):

Most `HTMLElement`'s don't have a `contentWindow` property. Try casting it to an `HTMLIFrameElement`.

```
const iframe = i.getDocument()!.activeElement! as HTMLIFrameElement;
this._originalFocusedElement = iframe.contentWindow.document.activeElement;
```